How to fix map annotation selection issues in iOS 17?
I'm working on MapKit for SwiftUI using iOS 17, where I have a custom annotation. When an annotation is selected, a DetailsView should be shown, but it does not work as expected.

Selecting an annotation does not trigger the DetailsView even though the annotation shows as selected on the map.

Following the WWDC23 Video: Meet MapKit for SwiftUI at 17:07, I have created a custom annotation that when selected, expands its size as expected. It is clearly stated that the annotation must have a tag(_:) attached to it for the selection to work.
But the Map(selection:) parameter does not seem to update correctly in order to trigger the DetailsView using the sheet(item:_:) modifier.
How can I ensure that the DetailsView is triggered as expected, and also have the annotation unselected when the view is dismissed?

Important: The animation must be kept when selected/unselected action is triggered.

This is the minimalistic code that I have extracted from my project:
import MapKit
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

  private var annotations = generateRandomLocations()
  @State private var selection: AnnotationModel?

  var body: some View {
    Map(selection: $selection) {
      ForEach(annotations) { annotation in
        AnnotationMarker(annotation: annotation)
      }
    }
    .sheet(item: $selection) { station in
      DetailsView(id: station.id)
        .presentationDetents([.medium])
    }
  }
}

struct DetailsView: View {
  var id: UUID
  var body: some View {
    Text("DetailsView: \(id)")
  }
}

#Preview {
  ContentView()
}

struct AnnotationMarker: MapContent {

  var annotation: AnnotationModel
  @State private var isSelected = false

  var body: some MapContent {
    Annotation(coordinate: annotation.coordinate) {
      CustomMarker(isSelected: $isSelected)
    } label: {
      Text(annotation.id.uuidString)
    }
    .tag(annotation)
    .annotationTitles(isSelected ? .visible : .hidden)
  }
}

struct CustomMarker: View {

  @Binding var isSelected: Bool

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Circle()
        .frame(width: isSelected ? 52 : 28, height: isSelected ? 52 : 28)
        .foregroundStyle(.green)

      Image(systemName: "house")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(width: isSelected ? 32 : 16)
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
    }
    .onTapGesture { withAnimation { isSelected.toggle() }}
  }
}

struct AnnotationModel: Identifiable, Hashable {

  let id = UUID()
  var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
  }
  var latitude: Double
  var longitude: Double
}

/// Create random location for testing purposes.
func generateRandomLocations(count: Int = 50) -> [AnnotationModel] {
  return (1...count).map { _ in
    let latitude = Double.random(in: (43.5673...43.6573))
    let longitude = Double.random(in: (3.8176...3.9076))
    return AnnotationModel(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
  }
}


you probably need a computed binding for the sheet's item so it doesn't interfere with the map selection

I have found the trick to fix this issue. First of all, it seems to be a bug with the Map item selection. If the Annotation has a label, a tap action on the label would trigger the Annotation selection as expected.
However, since it is required to not have the title, the trick is to pass the selection: AnnotationModel as a Binding to the CustomMarker, and manage the selected and unselected behaviors from there.
Below is the updated code with comments next to the added parts:
The ContentView where the Map is
struct ContentView: View {

  private var annotations = generateRandomLocations()
  @State private var selection: AnnotationModel?

  var body: some View {
    Map(selection: $selection) {
      ForEach(annotations) { annotation in
        AnnotationMarker(
          annotation: annotation, 
          selection: $selection // Pass the `selection` in the `AnnotationMarker`.
        ) 
      }
    }
    .sheet(item: $selection) { item in
      DetailsView(id: item.id)
        .presentationDetents([.medium])
    }
  }
}

The updated Annotation with the custom View
struct AnnotationMarker: MapContent {

  var annotation: AnnotationModel
  @Binding var selection: AnnotationModel?

  var body: some MapContent {
    Annotation(coordinate: annotation.coordinate) {
      CustomMarker(
        annotation: annotation, // Pass the `annotation` from the `ForEach` to the `CustomMarker `.
        selection: $selection) // Pass the `selection` to the `CustomMarker `.
    } label: {
      Text(String())
    }
    .tag(annotation) // The tag can now be set here.
    .annotationTitles(.hidden)
  }
}

And this is where the selection actions will be handled, within the CustomMarker.
struct CustomMarker: View {

  @State private var isSelected = false

  var annotation: AnnotationModel // Pass the `annotation` of this `CustomMarker`.
  @Binding var selection: AnnotationModel? // Defining which `annotation` is selected, if any.

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Circle()
        .frame(width: isSelected ? 52 : 28, height: isSelected ? 52 : 28)
        .foregroundStyle(.green)

      Image(systemName: "house")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(width: isSelected ? 32 : 16)
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
    }
    .onTapGesture { // If it is the selected `annotation` from the `ForEach`, define the selection.
      selection = annotation
      withAnimation(.bouncy) { isSelected = true }
    }
    .onChange(of: selection) { // If the previous selected `annotation` from the `ForEach` is unselected, perform the changes.
      guard isSelected, $1 == nil else { return } // Avoid having actions on unselected `annotations`.
      withAnimation(.bouncy) { isSelected = false }
    }
  }
}


Life Saver. For real, spent like 3 days trying to get pins to tap correctly.
